# Change specific bytes in Haskell ByteString

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a `Data.ByteString` and a list of desired changes `[(Int, Word8)]` where `Int` is an index and `Word8` is a new byte value. How to apply these changes in a most efficient way?

In `C` it would be a simple loop over the change list and direct in-place mutation in it: `buffer[pos] = value`. But I can't in-place mutate things in Haskell, am I? Does it mean that if I have a 100GB binary blob and need to change a single byte, in Haskell I have to make a full copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to apply these changes in a most efficient way?

[`mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.1.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:mapAccumL) lets you iterate over the `ByteString` in a stateful way, potentially updating each position. You can use this by tracking the current index, and popping off the appropriate change of the (sorted) list of changes as you reach each one.

> But I can't in-place mutate things in haskell, am I?

Some things yes, some things no. There are mutable arrays if that is the data structure you need.

> Does it mean that if I have a 100GB binary blob and need to change a single byte, in Haskell I have to make a full copy?

If that blob is stored in a `ByteString`, then yes. See also the rope data structure ([1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-rope), [2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rope)) for an idiomatic immutable alternative for which the answer is no. And of course, if that blob is stored in a mutable array, then no.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I track index inside `mapAccumL`? In Haskell we have no `i`-variable and I thought I should `zip` with `range (1, length)`, but `ByteString.zip` typings allow only zipping with another ByteString

Comment: oh, I can just include index along with change list into accumulator tuple